# Miller Rabin Proof

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In Miller Rabin test, let n - 1 = 2<sup>x</sup>s, then,
 if a<sup>s</sup> mod n = 1 or a<sup>s</sup> mod n = -1 then we say n is probably prime or if a<sup>2<sup>x</sup>s</sup> mod n = 1 then also we say n is probably prime but, 
How can we say surely that n is composite if a<sup>2<sup>x</sup>s</sup> mod n = 1.
I read the proof [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/millerrabin.pdf) and understood the case where we say n is probably prime but I'm a little confused about the case where a<sup>2<sup>x</sup>s</sup> mod n = 1.
If anyone could explain that would be quite helpful.

Comment: If $n$ is prime and $(a^{2^m s})^2 = a^{2^{m+1} s}  \equiv 1 \bmod n$ then $a^{2^m s} \equiv \pm 1 \bmod n$. Thus if $a^s \not \equiv 1 \bmod n$ and you don't obtain $-1$ in the $2^m$-th powers it means $n$ is not prime.

Comment: I watched a video on youtube which clearly stated that if we get 1 we should stop and it is guaranteed that the number is composite but if we get something else than 1 and -1 we should go to the next step. So that was what I wanted to know that why stop at 1 and how it is guaranteed that the number is composite.


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdylJqXCDGs
above is the url of the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start with $a^{s 2^N} \equiv 1 \bmod n,  a^s \not \equiv 1 \bmod n$ then by repeated squaring, at some point you'll obtain $x = a^{2^ms}, x \not \equiv 1 \bmod n, x^2 \equiv 1 \bmod n$, if $n$ is prime this implies $x \equiv -1 \bmod n$

(because for $n=p$ prime the polynomial $x^2-1$ has only two roots in the field $\Bbb{Z/p Z}$)